# How resource heavy is a Timer?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm running a timer like this:

```
    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Interval = 3000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
        myTimer.Start();
    }
```

It will trigger an event every 3rd second. The event is not very heavy I think, it is reading text from a file, comparing text length to the text in a textbox and will replace the text in the box if it has more characters.

But how resource heavy is the timer? 
And is it a bad idea to read text from a file every 3rd second (the file is a log file in plain text).

Comment: If you need to replace the contents of the textbox when the file is saved from another process, use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: I think it would be as heavy as you make the TimerEventProcessor handler. My suggestion is that before processing this handler, you stop the timer and start it back up when you are done processing your code.

Comment: @millimoose: I used that first, but even if the file is changed the event won't fire. I think it is because the file is in use by another process. It behaves really strange then. If the file is changed nothing happens until I click the file in explorer (no double click just select it) then it will fire..

Comment: @Alex: Thank you, I'll do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Timer is fairly lightweight, though it does depend a bit on which type of timer you're using.  Having a timer fire every 3 seconds is not likely to be a big deal, though if you're using a Windows Forms timer, make sure your Tick event handler is not doing any significant processing, as it happens in the UI thread.  (For example, check the file length using [`FileInfo.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) instead of "reading" the file, etc)

That being said, for watching for changes in a log file, [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) is likely better than using a timer and re-reading the file continually.  In addition to notifying you immediately when the file changes, it also will keep you from having to reading the file continually.

Comment: Thank you! Lots of good stuff in that answer. The FileSystemWatcher gave me problems I just didn't managed to solve. If I manually save the log file, it fires every time. But when it is used bu the 3rd part software it will be in use all the time. I know how to open a stream and read it anyways. But the watcher will not see the changes to the file, for some reason. I can even see the Date Modified getting updated in explorer and it won't fire - not until I select the file in explorer (weird) I guess I'll take the opportunity to learn using the Timer now, and switch when I have learned more.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as heavy as you make the `TimerEventProcessor` handler. While the `FileSystemWatcher` seem like it could be the answer, it is not always the case. My suggestion is that before processing this handler, you stop the timer and start it back up when you are done processing your code.